# Need a reg-ex to match a length in mm

Tags: regex, preg-match

Im using PHP preg_match() method. I am having trouble with a regular expression to match a mm length. The numeerical length can be a float...here are some exmaples of the data I am working on;

1.0mm

25.5mm

3mm

3 mm

3.3 mm

So bacially any integer or float proceeded by "mm" with or without whitespace between.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `'/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*mm/'` and you'll have the number in $1.

Explanation:

- `(` begin capturing group
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `(?:` begin non-capturing group
- `\.` litteral dot
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `)` end non-capturing group
- `?` the non-capturing group ("." + digits) may not be present
- `)` end capturing group
- `\s*` zero or more whitespaces (or tabs, etc.)
- `mm` literal "mm"

Comment: @streetpc - nearly there! but this reg-ex also returns boolean true on the following;

1.2m

(it needs to be strict an return true only on "mm")

Can this reg-ex be modified to do this?

Comment: The regex contains a litteral double "m" so it should only match "mm". If it doesn't, can you put the piece of code please?   @FM fixed that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a regex for this? if you use something like floatval on "123.122mm" it should give you 123.122 numeric and ignore the text.